# How to reference parameter selection in query?

Tags: sql, oracle, bi-publisher

Right now I have a query that shows the results based on the list of value parameter selected for 'role':

```
select distinct
i.control
,i.role
,i.entitlement
from ctrl_access_incident i
where i.role in nvl(:rolelov, i.role)
```

I want to add to the query to pull all the conflicting roles based on the role parameter that was selected-- so all the roles that have the same controls as the selected parameter.  How do I reference the selected parameter value?

Comment: Huh?  Please edit the question, show table definitions, and expected output.

Comment: I would have written the `WHERE` clause as `WHERE (i.role = :rolelov OR :rolelov IS NULL)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use `IN` or `INNER JOIN` as following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
CONTROL,
ROLE,
ENTITLEMENT FROM
ctrl_access_incident
WHERE CONTROL IN
(select distinct i.CONTROL
from ctrl_access_incident i
where (:rolelov is null or i.role= :rolelov))
```

OR

```
SELECT DISTINCT
C1.CONTROL,
C1.ROLE,
C1.ENTITLEMENT FROM
ctrl_access_incident C1
JOIN ctrl_access_incident C2
ON (C1.CONTROL = C2.CONTROL)
WHERE (:rolelov is null or C2.role= :rolelov)
```

Cheers!!